# While redirecting email with AppleScript the content of the email is duplicating. Why?

Tags: applescript

What I'm trying to do is setup a Mail.app rule to redirect all iTunes receipt emails to a specific notebook in Evernote. The following AppleScript adds the correct recipient and modifies the subject-line so I can include a pointer to the correct Evernote notebook. The problem is I can't figure out why the content of the email gets copied twice. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: For clarification, this script is run as part of a Mail.app rule. When an email comes in matching the rule the AppleScript below is run. If you're not familiar with Evernote's ability to add items via email it works like this: Every Evernote user receives a unique email address that allows items to be added directly to their Evernote account. Within the subject line certain keywords may be added to direct documents to specific folders (@Receipts) or to add specific tags (#cool).

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theMessages
    repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
        tell application "Mail"
            set newMessage to redirect thisMessage with opening window
            tell newMessage
                set subject of newMessage to "hello"
                make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"mine@email.com"}
                delete bcc recipients
                delete cc recipients
            end tell
            set the sender of newMessage to "me@me.com"
            delay 1
            -- send newMessage
        end tell
    end repeat
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: This may help for diagnostics: it happens after 'make new to recipient…'.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too but I can't figure out why it's happening or what my alternatives are to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Mail 4.6.1085 and a plain text e-mail. The body text of the e-mail doesn't get duplicated in this set-up at first, but then I noticed that it does get duplicated in another auto-reply function of mine. This is what happened:

1. write text e-mail with subject "evernote" 2) download e-mails,
   subject "evernote" triggers an auto-reply from my support e-mail,
   which looks normal
2. the support auto-reply (which was sent to
   myself, as it was a test) triggered the evernote script (below)
3. the evernote script quoted the original message and inserted a copy
   of the same message.

I think you can solve this by storing the original text and setting it again right before sending the message. The following doesn't seem to send messages with duplicate texts:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages
        repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
            tell application "Mail"
                set theText to content of thisMessage
                set newMessage to redirect thisMessage with opening window
                tell newMessage
                    set subject of newMessage to "hello"
                    make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"mine@email.com"}
                    delete bcc recipients
                    delete cc recipients
                end tell
                set the sender of newMessage to "me@me.com"
                set content of newMessage to thisText
                delay 1
                -- send newMessage
            end tell
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when I tried to forward a message (running 10.6-to 10.9)
I fixed it by storing the content of the new message before adding another subject etc...

```
set themessage to forward eachMail with opening window
set a to content of themessage
set thesubject to (subject of eachMail) as rich text
    tell themessage
        set subject to thesubject
        repeat with m in mailtos
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:m}
        end repeat
        set content to a
    end tell
```